# Python-too many values to unpack(csv file)

Tags: python, python-3.10

I am trying all the countries with a life expectancy greater than 75 from a csv file in the latest python but I keep getting the error:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

The specific section it says is wrong is:

```
Name,LifeExpectancy=line.rstrip().split(',')
```

the full code is:

```
fo = open ('country.csv', 'r')

line=fo.readline()
while line:
    Name,LifeExpectancy=line.rstrip().split(',')
    if LifeExpectancy !='NULL' and LifeExpectancy >='75.0':
        print(Name,LifeExpectancy)
        line=fo.readline()

fo.close
```

does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `csv` module?

Comment: You probably have a blank line in the file. `split()` returns a list of one empty string in that case.

Comment: BTW, it's easier to write the loop as `for line in fo:` so you don't have to assign `line` twice.

Comment: The second `line=fo.readline()` shouldn't be inside the `if`. You'll get stuck on the same line whenever the condition doesn't succeed.

Comment: You should convert the life expectancy to a number before comparing. If you compare as a string, `'9.0' > '75.0'` is true.

Comment: And using pandas would make everything easier.

Answer (score 1):

split() method of string returns list.
First check how many values do the list have:

```
list_with_splits = line.rstrip().split(',')
print(len(list_with_splits))
```

It probably has more than two elements.

Comment: I did this and it came back 10, theres 10 rows in the file but I only need the 2.

Comment: Now you have to tell the computer which indexes of the list you need i.e. list_with_splits[0], list_with_splits[1]